# Segmentation fault (core dumped) using nodejs and swig

Tags: node.js, swig

I'm using ubuntu 12.04LTS,I'm trying to create node extension.
ex.cxx:

```
    #include <stdio.h>

void user_connect(char user[],char date[]){

FILE* fichier=NULL;
fichier=fopen("log.txt","+a");
fprintf(fichier,"user:%s connected at :%s",user,date);
fclose(fichier);

}

void etat_periph(char periph[]){

FILE* fichier=NULL;
fichier=fopen("log.txt","+a");
fprintf(fichier,periph);
fclose(fichier);

}
```

ex.i:

```
%module example
 %{
 extern void user_connect(char user[],char date[]);
 extern void etat_periph(char periph[]);

 %}


 extern void user_connect(char user[],char date[]);
 extern void etat_periph(char periph[]);
```

binding.gyp:

```
 {
  "targets": [
    {
      "target_name": "ex",
      "sources": [ "ex.cxx", "ex_wrap.cxx" ]
    }
  ]
}
```

app.js:

```
var ex=require("./build/Release/ex");
var user="hs";
var current_date=new Date();
var date=current_date.toString();
var periph="led is on";

ex.user_connect(user,date);
ex.etat_perpih(periph);
```

I run the appropriate commands using swig to do the node extension,after creating the extension when I run node app.js I got this error message:

```
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

Comment: Execute the function from C and attach a debugger

Comment: @JensMunk: I didn't get nothing when I debug it

Comment: Are you saying that the C program works fine? If so, then you can conclude that the wrapper introduces the segmentation fault. I have seen this a couple of times and as a consequence I have changed some of the typemaps provided.